# What is wrong with my PHP script?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I want this php script to first decide whether or not it should send the following emails, all using data received from a form in another html file. At the moment I'm really not sure what I'm doing with php nor do I know where to start. For the sake of the task, I want the person to correctly identify the picture  and match it with pre-assigned passwords. Once they have done this correctly 2 emails would be sent. How would I go about formatting this?

I've adjusted my code with Ian and ThomasEliss' help (Thank you for your insight), however, when I click submit on my form, it simply takes me to the php file, displaying a blank screen. What am I doing wrong. Thank you for your help :)

```
<?php 
$captcha = $_REQUEST['captcha'] ;
$passwords = array();
$passwords[] = '2Vd27VFfkK' ;
$passwords[] = 'MjgxfNA5Qn' ;
$passwords[] = 'tg3K3GhS6W' ;
$passwords[] = 'n2m6GHfVSK' ;
$passwords[] = 'RTxqN5euFX' ;
$passwords[] = 'AJzsWwES6D' ;
$passwords[] = '24hAgsHuW3' ;
$passwords[] = 'xHzvW9kyFk' ;
$passwords[] = 'CyXH7VRhyp' ;
$passwords[] = 'QshfjUn75Z' ;
if(in_array($usrpassword, $passwords)) {
 $to1 = $_REQUEST['usremail'] ;
 $subject1 = "Joining"; 
 $email = "me@email.com" ; 
 $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
 $message1 = "
** This is an automated email, please do not reply **

Hello $name,

This email has been sent because this email address was submitted to our site requesting signup documents. 
If this was not you please ignore this email.
If it was you follow the link below to receive the required documents.

If you have any other questions feel free to email our Administration Officer.

Kind regards.
" ; 
 $headers = "From: Recruiting";
 $sent = mail($to1, $subject1, $message1, $headers) ;
    if($sent) 
    print "Your mail was sent successfully"; }
    else 
    print "We encountered an error sending your submission.
 Please refresh the page to try again."; })
 }
 $to2 = "me@email.com" ;
 $subject = "Signup Forms Requested" ; 
 $from = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
 $usremail = $_REQUEST['usremail'] ;
 $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'] ;
 $email = "me@email.com" ; 
 $message2 = "
  ** This is an automated email, please do not reply **

 Hello Administration Officer,

 The following email is to advise you that $from submitted a request for sign up forms.
 The email submitted was: $usremail

 They have recieved the required documents and have included the following comment in their submission:

 $comment

 If you have any questions or problems please email the Webmaster.

 Regards.

 email: me@email.com
" ; 
 $headers = "From: $email"; 
 $sent = mail($to2, $subject2, $message2, $headers) ; 
 if($sent) 
 {header( 'Location: http://example.com' ) ; }
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your submission."; }
}
else {
 {header( 'Location: http://example.com' ) ; }
}
?>
```

Comment: Any reason there are no '(', ')' around the if check?

Comment: You should use SwiftMailer, or a similar library, to help prevent against email injection.

Comment: Not sure but it's in my original code and it still doesn't work. Just displays a blank screen.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. What I'm trying to do is send data from a form on the condition that a correct passcode is entered. At the moment, when I hit submit in the html form, it redirects me to the php and displays a blank screen, without sending the email. Thanks for all of your help, it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the following

```
$password1 = '2Vd27VFfkK' ;
$password2 = 'MjgxfNA5Qn' ;
$password3 = 'tg3K3GhS6W' ;
$password4 = 'n2m6GHfVSK' ;
$password5 = 'RTxqN5euFX' ;
$password6 = 'AJzsWwES6D' ;
$password7 = '24hAgsHuW3' ;
$password8 = 'xHzvW9kyFk' ;
$password9 = 'CyXH7VRhyp' ;
$password10 = 'QshfjUn75Z' ;

if $usrpassword == $password1 || $usrpassword == $password2 || $usrpassword == $password3 || $usrpassword == $password4 || $usrpassword == $password5 || $usrpassword == $password6 ||$usrpassword == $password7 || $usrpassword == $password8 || $usrpassword == $password9 || $usrpassword == $password10
```

To

```
$passwords = array();
$passwords[] = '2Vd27VFfkK' ;
$passwords[] = 'MjgxfNA5Qn' ;
$passwords[] = 'tg3K3GhS6W' ;
$passwords[] = 'n2m6GHfVSK' ;
$passwords[] = 'RTxqN5euFX' ;
$passwords[] = 'AJzsWwES6D' ;
$passwords[] = '24hAgsHuW3' ;
$passwords[] = 'xHzvW9kyFk' ;
$passwords[] = 'CyXH7VRhyp' ;
$passwords[] = 'QshfjUn75Z' ;

if(in_array($usrpassword, $passwords))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to wrap your mailing in a function and then use a switch statement.

```
switch($_REQUEST['usrpassword']){
case '2Vd27VFfkK':
    mailFunction();
    break;
case 'MjgxfNA5Qn':
    mailFunction();
    break;
case 'tg3K3GhS6W':
    mailFunction();
    break;
case 'n2m6GHfVSK':
    mailFunction();
    break;
case 'RTxqN5euFX':
    mailFunction();
    break;
case 'AJzsWwES6D':
    mailFunction();
    break;
case '24hAgsHuW3':
    mailFunction();
    break;
case 'xHzvW9kyFk':
    mailFunction();
    break;
case 'CyXH7VRhyp':
    mailFunction();
    break;
case 'QshfjUn75Z':
    mailFunction();
    break;
default:
    //Do something to handle invalid passwords here
} 

function mailFunction(){
$to1 = $_REQUEST['usremail'] ;
$subject1 = "Joining"; 
$email = "noreply@jones.org.au" ; 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$message1 = "
** This is an automated email, please do not reply **

Hello $name,

Kind regards.
" ; 
$headers = "From: Recruiting";
$sent = mail($to1, $subject1, $message1, $headers) ;
if($sent){
        print "Your mail was sent successfully";
}    
else{
    print "We encountered an error sending your submission. Please refresh the page to try again.";
}
$to2 = "a@b.com" ;
$subject = "Signup Forms Requested" ; 
$from = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$usremail = $_REQUEST['usremail'] ;
$comment = $_REQUEST['comment'] ;
$email = "noreply@jones.org.au" ; 
$message2 = "
** This is an automated email, please do not reply **

 Hello Administration Officer,

 The following email is to advise you that $from submitted a request for sign up forms.
 The email submitted was: $usremail

 They have recieved the required documents and have included the following comment in their submission:

 $comment

 Regards,
" ; 
$headers = "From: $email"; 
$sent = mail($to2, $subject2, $message2, $headers) ; 
if($sent){
    header( 'Location: http://example.com' ) ; 
}
else{
    print "We encountered an error sending your submission."; 
    header( 'Location: http://404sqn.aafc.org.au/joinus.html' ) ;
} 
}
```

See PHP switch manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php .

Though I agree with @ian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23474522/2979715) because an array is much more manageable.  In that case, you could still wrap the mailer in a function and then just have:

```
if(in_array($usrpassword, $passwords)){
    mailFunction();
}
else{
    //Handle invalid passwords here
}
```

Comment: just curious to logic of using a switch statement, when all the outcomes are the same (mailFunction) if the password used called a different function the switch would make a bit more sense.

Comment: Very true.  That's why I agree with ian's answer.  Just wanted to provide another option so the the OP would hopefully learn a little more about PHP and it's available functions.